# Commit files inside directory with new directory structure and new files

Tags: git, gitlab, push, clone, commit

I have made a clone in my local computer that contains a certain file structure:

```
WD/
 |->folder1/
          |->file1.1.java
          |->file1.2.java
 |->folder2/
          |->file2.1.java
          |->file2.2.java
```

The new WD that I want to commit should have a completly new structure and also contains completely new files:

```
WD/
 |->new_folder1/
          |->file1.1.py
          |->file1.2.py
 |->new_folder2/
          |->file2.1.py
          |->file2.2.py
 |->new_folder3/
          |->file3.1.py
```

Can I simply commit and push this new WD or is this a bad practice/is there a more efficient way to do this procedure?

Comment: No, that's not an issue. That is the idea of versioning. There are no strict rules that changes you can make

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this structure is ok and you can push a new WD.

Before pushing make sure you use `git status` it will show you what changes will be made to your repository.